# Does Laravel 5 Cashier handle authentication?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm writing a simple subscription app, and I'm attempting to decipher the Laravel docs. I've set up users with the Authentication service provider plenty of times, but I've never messed with cashier. Can I theoretically just not use the authentication provider, and just use cashier to handle all of my permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched this more, and found a Scotch.IO example on GitHub. Apparently, you can combine both the Authentication service provider and the Cashier provider within a single User Model. You can do so like I have below, courtesy of Scotch.IO.

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Billable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'stripe_id', 'card_brand', 'card_last_four'
];
/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
}
```

[Here's a link to the repo.](https://github.com/scotch-io/laravel-cashier-course)